# How much energy does it take to schedule versus execute a CPU instruction?

Tags: cpu, alu, instruction-set

One of the justifications for vector instructions is that in a modern CPU, it takes more work to decode an instruction and do all the administrative work around it – scheduling, register renaming and so forth – than it does to actually execute it, so it is fundamentally more efficient to carry out several arithmetic operations in one instruction.

Can this be quantified? In a modern CPU – I would be happy with a figure for any of them – how much energy does it take to, say, multiply a pair of 64-bit numbers, versus the total amount of energy it takes to decode, schedule and execute a multiply instruction?

Comment: Do you have a specific CPU in mind, or even a CPU architecture, or an implementation of it? ARM or x86? If x86, Intel or AMD?

Comment: @Justme Like I said, I would be happy with a figure for any CPU architecture, any implementation, for which figures can be found. Of course, if it turns out that there exist figures for multiple modern CPUs, that would be even better; it would be interesting to compare instruction dispatch energy costs for RISC vs x64, for example.

Comment: RISC-V might be a good example to look at, as I believe there are high-quality, open-source implementations of its vector extension.

Comment: The energy to execute a multiplication depends on word length as well as operands. 0 * 0 or 1 * 1 may need much less energy than 1023 * 1023.

Comment: @rwallace I've worked on CPU designs, though my experience is quite limited. But I really don't think your question has merit, unless all you want is to know a bit of trivia for some case that bears little on any particular other question. There's no information about the vector operation -- it could be anything from vector addition of bytes to vector LambertW functions on 128 bit FP for all I can tell. And there a lot of handwaving about decode, schedule, etc. Make this a specific-use case and then you may see the justification you referenced. Otherwise, it seems a meaningless game to me.

Comment: @jonk I did specify the operation as 'multiply a pair of 64-bit numbers' (that being, as far as I know, the most expensive frequent arithmetic operation). The 'handwaving' is, as I said, all the rest of the work involved in carrying out an instruction. And it is a highly meaningful question, because it has a great deal of bearing on just how long vectors should be, which has been one of the more important questions in ISA design in recent decades.

Comment: @Uwe Okay, 64-bit word length and high entropy operands with about 50% 1 bits,  so no shortcuts in evaluation.

Comment: @rwallace To me, it looked as though you were mixing metaphors. But sure, you can say they weren't mixed. I just could not tell. Still, I don't think an answer would be meaningful. And I do have some modest experience, including working at Intel on chipset design. But let's leave it there with us disagreeing and me just saying that I'm not interested spending any of my time on it. Others can feel free, of course.

Comment: Vector operations are intended to be more efficient in terms of time rather than energy. It could be vector operations are utilizing more resources at a given time and consuming more energy. I’d think you’d need an accurate simulation of the chip to get hard numbers and only the manufacturers would have that. Consider high end GPUs that attempt to do as much work each clock cycle. These are vector processors and they consume plenty of energy. Time efficiency is the goal.

Comment: @Kartman No, it's both time and energy. https://yosefk.com/blog/its-done-in-hardware-so-its-cheap.html

Comment: I'm a bit confused about terminology here. What's "execution of an instruction" if it does *not* include handling the instruction? You're trying to artificially "extract" the cost of decoding. But decoding is absolutely part of what calculates the result, *especially* when you consider decoding might involve translation to microcode! I think to even approximate anything like "meaning" in this question, you'd need to first sit down and tell us what you mean with "energy spent scheduling, register naming and so forth". I'd argue there's really no sensible line to be drawn.

Comment: You ask whether *something* can be quantified, but then hesitate to actually *define that something*, even when asked for it. Maybe start with being super specific, like: *I want to consider an AMD Zen 2 8-core processor running at 3.6 GHz, doing a server-type benchmark 'XYZ'. With "scheduling overhead" I mean exactly these steps (concrete list of steps that map to functional units in the processor architecture), and with "actual execution" I mean (actual list of things). Is there some way I can approach estimating this?*

Comment: Because otherwise someone could just go and post an answer and say "the overhead is between 1% and 10000%, depending on what you consider", and would not be wrong. Fully with @jonk here, this sounds more like you just want *anything* to put on a slide for management, not want to get actual numbers!

Comment: @rwallace. The link says parallelization favors time  not energy. The vector operations lean on extra hardware so it’s more than just saving instruction fetches and decodes. Whether the vector operations save or burn energy is not a simple answer.  Are they a performance enhancement? That is fairly simple to quantify.

Comment: You can get a rough idea by looking at the increase in power consumption of your own CPU running a loop of scalar multiplication instructions vs. vector multiplication instructions. For 256 but multiplication power consumption is significantly higher than 32 bit, but not 8 times so.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but this gives some relevant figures: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Data-movement-is-overtaking-computation-as-the-most-dominant-cost-of-a-system-both-in_fig2_260520373